# Looping Nested Rows with Conditions : MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to get few of the table columns as it requires `recursive query` which I am not good at. So basically, if its a direct transfer, then remarks section is likely to be null. And if there is a halt in between origin and destination then I need to add the stations to my remarks column.

```
A to B -> nothing
B to C -> Via B
C -> D -> Via B,C
```

SQL query is:

```
CREATE TABLE IPhone (Id int, Country NVARCHAR(12), seqNo int, Send datetime2(0), Arrive datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO IPhone VALUES 
('1001','America','1', '2022-11-23 18:30:00.000',null),
('1002','China','2', '2022-11-24 08:18:00.000','2022-11-24 05:00:00'),
('1003','Argentina','3', '2022-11-25 18:30:00.000','2022-11-24 18:18:00.000'),
('1004','Saudi Arabia','4',null,'2022-11-25 20:30:00.000');
```

Tried

```
select  f.id,f.Country CountryFrom, t.Country CountryTo
, convert(varchar(4),f.seqNo) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),t.seqNo) seqNo
, f.Send, t.Arrive,concat('VIA ', f.Country ,', ', t.Country) Remarks from IPhone f inner join IPhone t on f.seqNo < t.seqNo order by id;
```

**Requirement is the following.** I tired looking into [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) but I am unbale to get the expected result. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; please only tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: @Larnu noted. Also please kindly help if possible.

Comment: That depends on what (R)DBMS you are *really* using... Don't "note" the problem, address it and fix the tag(s).

Comment: I'm using MSSQL Server.

Comment: @BhokluSingh then don't use tutorials made for MySQL like the one you have linked. Are you sure you are using MS SQL and not MySQL?

Comment: @BennySchärer Yes I am using SQL Server 2016. I am querying my tables using SQL server Management Studio.

Comment: @BhokluSingh good then have a look on how to actually construct a recursive query. What have you tried so far? What are the requirements other than using a recursive query? I can't dicerne what you are trying to do from just the screenshots you have posted.

Comment: @BhokluSingh how to differentiate between a direct flight and halt one?

Comment: @HariHaravelan if the seq is 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 then these are direct. .So if we do math here we se all returns 1 (2-1, 3-2, 4-3). .

Comment: @BennySchärer I posted this question here to ask guys who got the knack of SQL queries so that I can get some ideas on how to get this done. As of now I can only think of Recursive Query. Since Recursive query is quite complicated, therefore I'm seeking help from Gurus. I've also seen your level of query below. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive query is not required, This should work
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8843a/1

```
    SELECT f.id,
       f.country                      CountryFrom,
       t.country                      CountryTo,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), f.seqno) + '-'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), t.seqno) seqNo,
       f.send,
       t.arrive,
       CASE
         WHEN t.seqno - f.seqno = 1 THEN ''
         ELSE (SELECT 'VIA '
                      + (SELECT LEFT(country, Len(country) - 1)
                         FROM   (SELECT country + ', '
                                 FROM   iphone
                                 WHERE  seqno BETWEEN f.seqno + 1 AND
                                                      t.seqno - 1
                                 FOR xml path ('')) c (country)))
       END                            Remarks
FROM   iphone f
       INNER JOIN iphone t
               ON f.seqno < t.seqno
ORDER  BY id;
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. . But having 20k records and running this query will probably take a lot of time to process the data.

Comment: I just added few rows and it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Its working now after adding id=f.id. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If like mentioned in the comments you use MS SQL you can construct recursive queries like so.

```
with base as (

   <some initial data select>

    UNION ALL

    select ...
    from base
    
)
select ...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your query and provide some basic examples. Thanks.

Comment: @BhokluSingh This is the most basic example. I am not here to code for you but rather show you how to actually construct what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks. .I really appreciate your help. It has helped us all a lot. looking forward to get more good ideas from your end.